# Returning a PageReference from @HttpGet

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api

How can I render a Visualforce page from an `@HttpGet` method?

> HttpGet methods do not support return type of System.PageReference

My controller method looks like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/cases/*')
global with sharing class CaseController {

    @HttpGet
    global static PageReference updateCase() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        PageReference page = Page.CaseResponse;

        // do something

        return page;
    }
}
```

Can I write a method that is called inside `updateCase()` to return the page? Is it even possible?

**Update**

I realise I'm approaching it backward, but this was supposed to record a response in the URL params and render a page in response.

Comment: If you need to return a PageReference, you probably need an apex:actionFunction...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I updated the question with some info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **cannot** return a `PageReference` from an Apex REST method. Refer to the below excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm):

> These return and parameter types are allowed:
>
> - Apex primitives (excluding sObject and Blob).
> - sObjects
> - Lists or maps of Apex primitives or sObjects (only maps with String keys are supported).
> - User-defined types that contain member variables of the types listed above.

---

Furthermore, why would you really need it? The time you expose an API, you are not dealing with a UI component, but necessarily integration. It's upon the caller to decide what to do after they receive the response.

Comment: So I should switch it out for a SOAP method or something, right?

Comment: No. That is not going to help either. I am not sure about your use case, but you are getting the overall API implementation wrong. APIs are exposed to provide an interface to external systems to be able to perform some operations in your system without the need of interacting through any GUI.

Comment: I'm trying to leverage it to record a response in the params and render a page. I might have to rethink the approach.